# "An error" when looking at my achievements

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, network-profile, achievements-dialog

I got a small & temporary error when looking at my achievements in my network profile (by clicking the achievements / cup icon now hidden by the error):

[image: achievements icon covered by a light yellow "An error" box]

I had a green sign there, and today I had a simple achievement:

> You've earned the "Booster" badge (Share a link to a post later visited by 300 unique IP addresses) for "Using AssertionError and assertions in java".

Comment: "temporary error" - maybe was a temporary network error. It works fine for me.

Comment: Possibly. I'm on a wired network itself, on a stable DSL, so if this is the case it is either at the end of SO or somewhere in between.

Comment: I am also on a wired network. Sometimes a few glitches like this do happen. Example glitch that I've noticed is: "Add comment" link (not the button that appears after starting to enter the text of the comment) sometimes moves the page up. It is usually fixed by reloading the page. But I've never seen an "error..." message like that really.